# Django ALLOWED_HOSTS not changing

Tags: django, gunicorn

I have a django app hosted on a DO linux droplet running nginx and gunicorn.

I am trying to point the domain to the IP.

But I get the below error when I try to open the webapp in browser

```
    DisallowedHost at / 
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'example.com'. 
    You may need to add 'example.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS. 
    
    Request Method: GET 
    Request URL:    http://example.com/ 
    Django Version: 4.2.1 
    Exception Type: DisallowedHost 
    Exception Value:     Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'example.com'. You may need to add 'example.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

But in my settings.py, I already have the domain added as below (x.x.x.x is the IP):

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['x.x.x.x' ,'example.com', 'www.example.com']
```

In the error message in browser, when I look at local vars allowed_host, I can only see the IP (which was the earlier setting before I added the domain):

```
Variable    Value
allowed_hosts   ['x.x.x.x']
domain  'example.com'
host    'example.com'
msg 
("Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'example.com'. You may need to add "
 "'example.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.")
port    ''
self    <WSGIRequest: GET '/'>
```

I restarted the gunicorn but still nothing changes.

```
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```

Why is the change in allowed_hosts not reflecting ?

**EDIT:**

If I do pkill gunicorn and then start it again, like below, the changes are picked and it works:

```
pkill gunicorn
gunicorn -c conf/gunicorn_config.py myproject.wsgi --timeout 120
```

But the static files are still not loaded if I open using domain name but loaded if I open using IP address.

I get 302 found status for static file requests.

Here's the nginx configuration file:

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com x.x.x.x;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

location /static/ {
        alias /root/myproject_webapp/staticfiles/;
}

location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:3000;
}
}
```

Also, I don't understand why restarting gunicorn did not work in the first place.

Comment: Did you try restarting the nginx server `sudo systemctl restart nginx`?

Comment: @MohammadGolamDostogir Yes did that as well.